# OpenCV Noise Removal of video from static camera

Tags: c++, opencv

I Have an application that reads a video taken from a static camera, this is: The camera captures a scene from always the same spot.

In the scene, sometimes there's objects I need to recognize, which don't have many features to to match against (and their resolution is not so great). I wanted to denoise the scene to capture the objects moving.

What are my best options of algorithms to denoise it without losing much sharpness on the image?

Comment: too board, at least give some code of what your special case

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated question, and what to choose depends on the type of noise, the hardware you are running on and the runtime constraints.

Personally, I like non-local means denoising in many situations, but it really depends on the exact conditions.